# Why does an SKSpriteNode subclass work without encode(with:)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, protocols, nscoding

The [`NSCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding) protocol states:

> Any object class that should be codeable must adopt the NSCoding protocol and implement its methods.

The two required methods are `init?(coder: NSCoder)` and `func encode(with: NSCoder)`.

[`SKSpriteNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode) inherits from [`SKNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode) which conforms to the protocol. When writing a new `SKSpriteNode` subclass, Xcode's autocomplete will suggest the following code to satisfy the `NSCoding` protocol requirement:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

A call to super also works:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Why does this code satisfy the `NSCoding` requirements without implementing `encode(with: NSCoder)`?

Comment: 9.2. For me, that autocomplete message is not triggered until I start writing the subclass, like `class MySprite: SKSpriteNode {
    init()
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode will only tell you to add a required initializer if you write your own designated initialiser in the subclass, but not the `encode` method, correct?

This is because in fact, the requirements of `NSCoding` has already been implemented in the superclass, `SKSpriteNode`. That's why you don't need to implement `encode`. It has been inherited.

However, initializers are different. You can only inherit initialisers from your superclass under the following [rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html):

> **Rule 1**
>
> your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> **Rule 2**
>
> If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.

Look at rule 1! The designated initialisers will only be inherited if you don't have any designated initialisers yourself! So by adding this:

```
init() {}
```

you are adding a designated initialiser to your class, which stops the class from automatically inheriting the initialisers from the superclass. This is why you have to add a `required init`.

Comment: Ahh, thank you... a light bulb just clicked on. Sometimes it's frustrating not to be able to see how Apple's classes are implemented. But I guess since Swift is open source now we can take a look at it.